# What kind of partition do I want to install Ubuntu on?

Tags: system-installation

I'm installing the latest Ubuntu on a single partition, and I'm not sure which "use as" to select the partition for. Any help? My options are -

```
Ext4 and 3 journaling file system
Ext2 file system
Btrfs journaling file system
JFS journaling file system
XFS journaling file system
Fat16 file system
Fat32 file system
NTFS journaling file system
Swap area
Reserved BIOS boot area
Physical volume for encryption
Do not use this partition
```

My partition is 15gbs.

Comment: Ext4 is the usual default - why not choose the install or install on free space option?

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly want to use `Ext4`.  It's the best out of them all when it comes to functionality and efficiency for Ubuntu.  It should be the default.

Don't forget that you can always install to free space and let the automagic installer take care of everything.